# float and positioned element stacking order

Tags: html, css

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_and_float) and [this blog](https://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/), when z-index is not used, positioned elements should always stack over the float elements when they overlap. However, the example in the MDN link doesn't justify that. How come?

Comment: both link go to same url..then why you are using twice??

Comment: @Leothelion, probably a mistake???

Comment: well if its mistake then how we will compare??

Comment: sorry, corrected the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the link you provided:
The stacking order is -

1. Background and borders of the root element
2. **Descendant blocks in the normal flow, in order of appearance (in HTML)**

As this stacking order is before any of the others, it take priority - so DIV#1 will be behind other floating & positioned DIVs, ignoring normal DIVs.

Comment: DIV#4 is defined after DIV#1. However, DIV#1 is stacked above DIV#4. DIV#4 is not positioned though. Does this mean that when no z-index is used, floated and positioned element always stack above the non-positioned elements regardless of the order of appearance in HTML? But the positioned and floated element stack in the order of appearance in HTML.

Comment: Because it's not positioned, it ignores the rules above. If it's positioned or floating, it follows the rules above.